# Reset a git branch globally (for all users)

Tags: git, github, git-branch, remote-branch

In our current workflow, we have 2 main git branches:

`master` - stable release branch

`testing` - were everyone tests their code

Now every developer creates new branches for each feature they develop. When they are done, they merge it to `testing`, and when our QA says it's good to go, they merge their branch into `master` which gets deployed into production.

As time passes, our `testing` branch get polluted with commits that never make it to production. Abandoned features, stuff that got rewritten instead of fixed and other things.

To keep `master` and `testing` in a somewhat consistent state, we'd like to "reset" `testing` from time to time. Right now, we do so by entirely removing `testing` and re-branching it from `master`.

The big problem here is that we need to make sure that every single developer also remove his local `testing` branch and checks out a fresh copy of it.
If one developer forgets to do that and pushes to testing again, all the dirty commits that we are trying to get rid of are back.

Is there any way to reset a branch on the server in a way that it distributes to all users?

An acceptable solution would also be putting the `testing` branch in a state where nobody can push to it anymore without doing a reset locally. But I can't think of a way how to do it.

Creating a diff between `master` and `testing` and reverting commits is not an option as this prevents each of these commits to ever go into testing again.

Ideally, I'd have a script that performs this reset periodically and no interaction (other than `git pull`) is needed on each users local environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "no, you can't do that".

Remember that each clone is a complete stand-alone entity<sup>1</sup> that is little different from the source repository it was cloned-from, except for its `origin` and (depending on clone options) some of the initial branch states.<sup>2</sup>  Once someone has picked up a branch named `testing` and called it `origin/testing`:

- they have the commits that you let them have; and
- they have a reference ("remote-tracking branch") named `origin/testing` that their git will update automatically, and even prune (delete) if directed, when they connect to remote `origin`.

So far so good, and this "automatic prune" action sounds great.  If you can convince them to set `remote.origin.prune` to `true`:

```
$ git config remote.origin.prune true
```

then once you *delete **your*** branch named `testing`, *their* `origin/testing` will go away automatically on their next `git fetch origin`.

The problem comes in when *they* create a branch named `testing`.  Their git *won't* delete this branch unless and until *they* ask it to.  As far as their git is concerned, their private branches are their private branches.  You can't convince their git to delete their private `testing` any more than you can convince their git to delete their private `experiment-22`.  They created it; it's their repository; they keep control of it.

(Note that they also keep control of automatic pruning, since they can `git config` the `remote.origin.prune` setting away, or to `false`, at any time as well.  That setting is meant for their convenience, not yours—it goes with their `remote.origin.fetch` settings, which they change so that their `git fetch` changes what it does; its initial default setting is something they created when they ran `git clone`.)

You *can* continue with this model, provided you get all your developers to do their own controlled deletion or cleaning of this branch label.  But it's not the way to go.  Instead, you should use another model: create a new, *different* branch label for your developers for the new (and different) line of development you're doing.

For instance, you might have `dev-feature-X` as a temporary branch that your developers can all share for working on Feature X.  When you're all done with it, you keep or delete it at leisure, and your developers pick up the deletion automatically (with the prune setting) or not at their leisure.  Meanwhile you've created `dev-feature-Y` as a temporary branch that your developers can all share for working on Feature Y, and so on.

---

<sup>1</sup>Ignoring special cases like "shallow" clones that don't apply here, at least.

<sup>2</sup>If you clone without `--mirror`, the source's branches become your remote branches, and you have no local branches at all until you check one out (usually `master`, usually as the last step of the `clone` command).  Also, clone can't see the source's hooks, so those are not cloned.  Neither is any other special state in the `.git` directory, such as items in `.git/info`.  None of these affect the principles of ordinary branch usage, though.

Comment: The first line seems true. This is simply not possible. It's no problem telling everyone to set `remote.origin.prune`, but since I will delete the branch on the server and re-create it immediately, it won't have any effect. Next push will push all dirty commits back up. We already use feature branches, but we need the testing branch for continuous integration, to have one central point that gets build and deployed automatically and that QA can test.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are implementing your CI, but if you simply have multiple CI branches that you cycle through ("testing_1", "testing_2", etc) and leave most of them deleted most of the time, you'll only encounter problems if a developer has managed to not run "git fetch" (and hence prune) the branch for long enough for it to have come back into rotation.  Same basic idea as above, just slightly different details...

Answer (score 2):

> As time passes, our testing branch get polluted with commits that never make it to production. Abandoned features, stuff that got rewritten instead of fixed and other things.

How is this possible? Clearly if a feature gets abandoned, then you should remove it from your testing branch as well, because it seems to be your gate keeper. Basically, if you say that your testing branch gets polluted with time, then it defeats the whole purpose of a testing branch, because now you are testing something which doesn't represent the code which you want to push to production.

If something doesn't make it, then the developer should revert his changes and push a commit to the testing branch where the change gets reverted as well.

In your scenario you should merge from testing to production either all or nothing.

Comment: While this is how it *should* work, in practice it doesn't. It's impossible to prevent 20 developers from 'forgetting' about their features. Even worse when business decides to put something on hold and the dev doesn't know whether this may still be needed 3 months later or if it is dead already.

Comment: Did you try rebase? Perhaps this does the trick then:
http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing

Comment: Did you just post any random link you found? Rebasing has nothing to do with my problem.

Comment: @MrTweek, how do issues get resolved in your system? Perhaps they should remain open (or in some other non-closed state) until the relevant code gets merged *or removed from testing*.

Comment: Chris, it's a very agile environment and commits are not necessarily connected to a ticket.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to reset the state of the development branch by merging in the master branch in a special way.

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b new_testing
git merge -s ours testing # this creates a merge commit, but
                          # its tree is that of the current work-tree
                          # which in our case is the same as master
git checkout testing
git merge ours_testing
git branch -d new_testing
```

We need to create the temporary `new_testing` branch since the merge strategy `ours` keeps the current tree rather than the other tree, and there is no equivalent `theirs` strategy.

After this you will end up with a branch structure like

```
*         (testing) merge
|\
| *       (master) last commit on master
* |       last commit on testing
| |
```

But the content of testing will match the content of master.

The advantage of this is that anyone that has local commits on testing that
have occurred after `last commit on testing` will be able to rebase their changes up onto `origin/testing` as normal.

Since this shouldn't interrupt the usual development flow, there's no reason why it can't be done frequently (nightly?).

Comment: I just tried this out. While it does what it does what I need, it only does not distribute this information to users. As soon as any user runs `git push`, all the dirty commits are back in the branch.

Comment: A simple push will not put the bad commits back, only a `push --force` will. But if your developers are using `push --force` everything is going to go royally wrong, they'll be overwriting each others changes etc. If they rebase they'll be able to push, but in that case the bad commits will be gone. And as @jthill mentions you can prevent accepting `push --force` by setting `denynonfastforward` in the remote repository.

Answer (score 1):

> If one developer forgets to [rebase] and pushes to `testing` again, all the dirty commits [from an abandoned `testing` tip] that we are trying to get rid of are back.

You can't control what goes on in other people's repos, but you can control what they push to yours.

> An acceptable solution would also be putting the testing branch in a state where nobody can push to it anymore without doing a reset locally. But I can't think of a way how to do it.

This pre-receive hook will refuse pushes introducing unwanted history via merge:

```
#!/bin/sh
#  Do not permit merges from unwanted history
#set -x
err=0
while read old new ref; do              # for each pushed ref

        [[ ${old%[^0]*} = $old ]] && continue # new branches aren't checked.

        nomerge=$(git for-each-ref refs/do-not-merge --format='%(objectname)^!')

        if [[ $( git rev-list --count --ancestry-path --boundary $old..$new $nomerge
         ) != $( git rev-list --count --ancestry-path --boundary $old..$new ) ]]; then
                echo "$ref doesn't allow merges from outdated history"
                err=1
        fi
done
exit $err

# why it works:

# if adding nomerge commits' parents as ancestors has any effect, then the
# nomerge commits are reachable without going through $old, i.e. they're 
# in some merged history. So check whether adding the abandoned commits as
# explicit ancestors to the push makes them show up, and refuse it if so.
```

To mark unwanted commits, refer to them under `refs/do-not-merge`, for instance

```
git config alias.no-further-merges-from \
  '!f() { git update-ref "refs/do-not-merge/$1-@`date +%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S`" "$1"; }; f'
```

So the ritual for abandoning `testing` is

```
git no-further-merges-from testing
git checkout -B testing master
```

and if you want to mark previously abandoned tips you can refer to them by sha or by any other expression, say

```
git no-further-merges-from 'testing@{last october 31}'
```

Comment: `git config receive.denynonfastforward true` does not seem to have any effect on this behaviour. It still pushes all dirty commits from the local branch to the new and clean remote branch.